# Multiline regex starts with ends with one of with special word in between

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that get's urls that have a special word
The urls can have different protocols and finish with different characters for example

```
1 "http://test1.special.com" => should match
2 https://test2.special.com; => should match
3 //test3.special.com; //test3.special.com) => should match twice
4 http://test4.notspecial.com =>no match
```

I wrote this pattern

```
\/\/(.*).*?(special.*(\)|\;|\"))
```

line 3 is selected as only one result instead of two separate matches
https://regex101.com/r/FOQgjN/1
How can I do this so it selects one url even if there's multiple per line?
Thanks

Comment: Try `\/\/([^);\"\s]*?special[^);\"\s]*)[);\"]` if nothing else helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `?` to all the expressions that match multiple characters. That makes it non-greedy. So like

```
\/\/(.*?).*?(special.*?(\)|\;|\"))
```

Comment: `(.*?).*?` makes very little sense, it is the same as `\/\/().*?(special.*?(\)|\;|\"))`, but the empty `()` also do not make much sense in this pattern. So, `\/\/.*?(special.*?[);\"])` might be  a cleaner pattern version.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right about that but it already didn't make sense in the OP's question. I probably could have given a better solution, but I just wanted to build on what was already there in OP's question

Comment: When other users come here, they might like this `.*?.*?` and will start copying it, and once it will end with a catastrophic backtracking and a useless question on SO. Providing regex solutions that do not follow best practices leads to this unwelcome effects.

Answer (score 1):

Granted, it can be more specific, but maybe the following would suit your needs:

```
(?:https?:)?\/\/.*?(?=["; )]|$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wcKZBZ/1)

---

- `(?:https?:)?` - Optional non-capture group to match 'http:' or 'https:';
- `\/\/.*?` - Match two forward slash characters and 0+ (Lazy) characters other than newline upto;
- `(?=["; )]|$)` - Positive lookahead to assert next character is either in character class '["; )]' or the end-line anchor.